# UIcollectionview's cell item hidden or not even being dequeue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need to display an arrays of users on a `UICollectionView` with 1 cell 1 user info.
Based on the user online status, will determine on whether to show the online green dot on each cell.
My main problem now is when I scroll down to display more users, the online green dot some disappear and some will still remain. But when more cells being reuse, the green dot will randomly display on other cells. What should I implement to keep all the green dots display properly?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if user.online != "online"{
        cell2.onlineIcon.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some of your code

Comment: @PPL edited my question

Comment: Here what is user object & cell2?

Comment: @PPL user object is an array of users, so cell2 will display each user in the collectionview

Comment: Check answers, it is correct

Comment: @PPL thanks bro, just a simple solution help my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your cellForItemAt code with below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if user.online != "online"{
        cell2.onlineIcon.isHidden = true
    } else {
        cell2.onlineIcon.isHidden = false
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please accept answer if my answer is work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly mentioned cells are reused.

When you set a value of a UI element in an `if` clause you have to add an `else` clause to set a default value

```
if user.online != "online" {
   cell2.onlineIcon.isHidden = true
} else {
   cell2.onlineIcon.isHidden = false
}
```

or much simpler in one line

```
cell2.onlineIcon.isHidden = user.online != "online"
```